# How to ensure == will always work with primitives as an equality test

Tags: java, equals, equality, primitive, autoboxing

From what I understand, if I have two `long` or `int`, the `==` operator to test equality of values will not work sometimes due to autoboxing.

What do I need to do to ensure that `==` will work in every possible scenario when dealing with primitives?

Comment: If both operands are primitive types, it won't box...

Comment: AIUI, comparing `double` values with `==` is rarely a good idea.

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=197 has some info

Comment: @DuncanJones it's a typecast `double` from `int` or `long`

Comment: Can you provide a code sample the triggers the problem you are describing?

Comment: I read it on an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586223/how-does-the-tostring-equals-object-methods-work-differently-or-similar

Comment: For floating point data types, `abs(d1 - d2) < someDegreeOfAccuracy` is a better idea.

Comment: You read it in a wrong answer. Ignore it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backward compatibility demands (and the JLS agrees) that if you had an expression like

```
double a = ..
double b = ...
if (a == b) // condition
```

This condition must work the same way it did before auto-boxing as after autoboxing.  This means autoboxing cannot and must not apply here.

In fact autoboxing is never used to compile an == expression if it can use unboxing instead.

```
Integer i = 1000;
int j = 1000;
System.out.println(i == j); // is true
```

In this case unboxing is chosen over boxing.

Comment: The statement `autoboxing is never used to compile an == expression` is not quite true.  If `a` is declared as `Object` and `b` is declared as `int`, `a==b` will autobox `b` to an `Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

The JLS (§15.21.1) says:

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).

So the problem you describe occurs only if *both* operands are boxed types (`Double`, `Integer`, etc.).  Whether the operand type is boxed or not depends on how the operand is declared.  If it's a variable, field or parameter, it depends on the type used to declare the name; if it's a method call, it depends on the return type used when the method is declared; if it's the result of some other operation like `+`, it should already be unboxed; if a typecast has been applied, the cast will tell you what the type is.

As others have said, you usually shouldn't use `==` to compare doubles or floats due to rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Fafaik you can not get boxing with two primitives. Boxing occurs when you were to take (for example) and `int` and an `Integer`, or a `double` and a `Double`. Unboxing get the primitive from the "box" (the Object equivalent) to then compare the two primitives with the `==` operator, in which case there is no guarantee they are the same. If you have two `double`s however you will not have this problem.

Comment: No, this is wrong.  If you compare a `double` and a `Double`, it will unbox the `Double`, not box the `double`.

Comment: I am sorry, you are completely correct - I will change this straight away.